# C++ Draw a small dot in the center of a screen

Tags: c++, graphics

I want to draw a small dot at the center of the screen so that it must remain after running of any application. A dot should stay even after I launch an application in full screen mode. Like a dead pixel.

I have already installed Visual C++ on my computer with Windows 7. I have some experience with C++, but I never worked with graphics under Windows OS.

How can I draw a dot on a screen?

Comment: There isn't, and shouldn't be, a way to create a fully omni-modal window as you want.

Comment: If you want to use sniper rifles un-scoped, just use a bit of tape or something like everyone else ;)

Comment: Hehe, next question is bound to be about how to write an aimbot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many graphics cards have overlay features, and it is likely possible to set one up to be foremost on the screen regardless of what other applications are rendering in other layers.

But the method to do that would be specific to the video card model and driver.

Or, you can try to get your code inside the application doing full-screen rendering, find their rendering context, and draw to it at the ideal time.  Which still requires a bunch of variants for all the different graphics APIs.

[Here](http://s0beit.me/reverse-engineering/steam-gameoverlayui-hook-microsoft-rage/#more-39) is someone who describes Steam's attempt to solve the portability issue (with a zillion implementations) and how to take advantage of that.

Comment: One can also trap and redirect Direc3D (or OpenGL, etc.) calls and upon the *page flip* call, just put a pixel in the middle of the framebuffer. I mention this because the OP's most likely intention is to use that pixel as an aiming guide for FPS games. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @yzt: That appears to be how the Steam overlay component used by the linked blog works.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a properly positioned 1x1 pixel (or whatever size you need) window with no borders or title bar, all client area and paint it appropriately. It's important that the window is created with the `WS_EX_TOPMOST` style. As long as your program is running, the window will be visible as long as there are no other windows with that style overlapping it.

I've done this as a prank. It worked really well over a full-screen OpenGL game (Quake III). I installed it on a friend's machine so that it would flash the word LOSER! in big letters in the center of the screen at random times during the game.

This worked perfectly well on an XP system. I imagine it should work on Windows 7.

Comment: Yeah, those were the days!